# Using pathfinder and merge without effecting vector detail

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I've followed [how do I use pathfinder on multiple objects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-do-i-use-pathfinder-on-multiple-objects) so that I could cut straight down the middle of my vector. Clicking the merge within the pathfinder panel works as intended but the detail of the avatar reduces in quality. I suspect this may be a duplicate on Graphic Design, but I have looked with no luck. If this is the case please don't hesitate to flag and point me in the right direction.

Detailed Problem!
[image]
[image: Image 1]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To crop half of the avatar I would use the knife tool - and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> as you drag to get straight blade. Any gradients you would have to check. 
Merge joins objects with the same fill and removes all strokes and overlap.

Comment: It's the 'removes strokes' that's the functional words here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your final goal is, but if you're just looking to show half of the avatar/artwork, a clipping mask would do the trick, without losing any vector detail.

Simply create a colored rectangle around the half of the art you want to show, then select all (Cmd-A), and right-click. In the contextual menu, choose "Make Clipping Path".  You can also find this command under the Object Menu; Object > Clipping Path > Make.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you could combine a couple methods. You need to expand any strokes so all you have are filled shapes.

[image: INITIAL SHAPE]

Then you can use a clipping mask to cut the item you want into the shape (in this case, in half).

[image: CLIPPING MASK SETUP]

[image: CLIPPING MASK APPLIED]

Then you need to use TRIM in the pathfinder toolbox. Should trim it all up nicely to the outside of the box.

[image: TRIM APPLIED]

[image: GRADIENT NEEDS RE-MERGING]

[image: AFTER RE-MERGE]

I use this all the time in pattern design - just **make sure** you have no strokes that aren't expanded. This approach works on gradients too, but you may have to select gradient pieces and re-merge them after the trim if they are having issues.

Comment: Hey Summer, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer! I edited it a bit to make it a little more formatted. Feel free to edit it again if I misplaced anything. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: thx Mark! I appreciate the help - much better! hahaha I'm better in programs than in forums. :)